# How can I open my extern file browser (Nautilus) with C-c C-a f in emacs Org Mode using attachments?

Tags: org-mode

I work with attachments (`C-c C-a`) in Emacs Org Mode.

I configured the variable `org-file-apps` to open pdf with the default PDF Viewer of my OS (in my case evince in Ubuntu 18.04), when I use the key binding `C-c C-a o` (instead of `C-c C-a **O**` to force emacs to open it in emacs).

I want the same for directories, but I don't know how to configure the variable `org-file-apps` to start nautilus with the desired directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation string of `org-file-apps` (partially quoted in the following text) and the [uri-description for the `nautilus` command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98562/nautilus-special-uris) the Elisp code at the bottom should work.

Relevant part of the documentation string of `org-file-apps`:

> Org mode uses system defaults for different file types, but
>   you can use this variable to set the application for a given file
>   extension.  The entries in this list are cons cells where the car identifies
>   files and the cdr the corresponding command.
>
> Possible values for the file identifier are:
>   ...
>    `directory'   Matches a directory

```el
(setq org-file-apps (cons '(directory . "nautilus file://%s") org-file-apps))
```